# VSC @TypeScript Observable error

Tags: typescript

```
import "introcs";

export function main(): void {
    print ("Intro");
    print ("a");
    print ("b");
    promptString("What would like to do?", forkMain);
} 

export function forkMain(choice: string): void {
    clear();
    if ("a") {
        storyA();
    } else if ("b") {
        storyB();
    } else {
        main();
    }
}

export function storyA(): void {
    print ("result");
    print ("1");
    print ("2");
    promptNumber("What would like to do?", forkA);
}

export function forkA(choice: number): void {
    clear();
    if (1) {
        storyC();
    } else if (2) {
        storyD();
    } else {
        storyA();
    }
 }

export function storyB(): void {
    print ("result");
    print ("3");
    print ("4");
    promptString("What would like to do?", forkB);
}

export function forkB(choice: number): void {
    clear();
    if (1) {
        storyE();
    } else if (2) {
        storyF();
    } else {
        storyB();
    }
 }

export function storyC(): void {
    print ("the end story c");
}

export function storyD(): void {
    print ("the end story d");
}

export function storyE(): void {
    print ("the end story e");
}

export function storyF(): void {
    print ("the end story f");
}

main();
```

Hey folks, above is the code I'm in the beginning stages of working on for a CYOA, but I'm having trouble with the printing stage, as once it gets to forkB stage of the code, I get the below error:

```
"severity: 'Error'
message: 'Argument of type '(choice: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'choice' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.'"
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here? I think it's with my syntax, but I'mm unsure

Answer (score 0):

The definition for `promptString` is:

```
function promptString(prompt: string, cb: (value: string) => void): void;
```

But in your code you are passing the second parameter `cb` as `forkB` which is typed as `(choice: number): void` -- where `number` not compatible with `string`.

Change your `forkB` as:

```
export function forkB(choice: string): void {
    // ...
}
```